# Chrome headless capability of showing pop-up windows

Tags: web-testing, katalon-studio

I've created a test that handles the 'Open File' Explorer window during a file upload process.
The thing is that chrome headless by default doesn't show the 'Open File' window, therefore the test fails. In Firefox headless though, the window is popping up and it works great (by default).
Does someone know if there is a capability that I can use to make chrome show me this window?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As I see, it is a know bug in headless implementation of Chrome: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=696481